# How can I approach leaving a research Job before my paper is ready to be published?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, team

I've been working at my current employer for the past 1.5 years - I've been in my current team for 1 year. We are a research team within a government department, and for the last year have undertaken a research project into a new way to carry out a particular method.

The methods and the work we've developed are new and innovative (and very interesting to the wider academic community - we've been told this by our academic partners) and there is the possibility of producing some form of publication (whether in an academic journal or as a "working paper" style).

To this end, I have written up our methodology, background, results etc. It's about 100 pages long and a true repository of all knowledge and research undertaken & results. As I thought we might publish something, I have written it in the style of a publication, and any further work would draw extensively from this (it was essentially be a case of cutting it down to a reasonable length). 90% of it is my work and writing.

If not me, there is a single person in my team who might be capable of taking what is there and cutting it down into a report - but they have had no experience do so before. I was lead on this project from the start, and no-one else has been involved in all its aspects.

I plan to hand in my notice in the next week (for reasons that aren't important to this question).

My question: If my team go ahead and eventually publish a report on this project based on this work, do I have any claim to authorship? Is there any enforceable basis to ensure that, if I leave, and it is published, my credit is kept?

Comment: Have previous publications listed all the team members as authors? Or has it been 'by Department of X' or 'Dr. Leader and underlings'? Something like that.

Comment: @Kozaky A paper that was published previously, very similar to the style I am considering, was credited to the individual authors (with their team/department listed). This was published following a gov conference, on our department website, not submitted to a wider journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... there is the possibility of
>   producing some form of publication (whether in an academic journal or
>   as a "working paper" style).
>
> ...
>
> My question: If my team go ahead and eventually publish a report on
>   this project based on this work, do I have any claim to authorship?

To address the academic journal side: you haven't specified your field, and there is some variability, but the [recommendations of the International Committee of Medical Journal Editors](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html) seem to be cited in other fields as well, perhaps because other fields don't have such clear guidance in-house.

> The ICMJE recommends that authorship be based on the following 4 criteria:
>
> - Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work; AND
> - Drafting the work or revising it critically for important intellectual
>     content; AND
> - Final approval of the version to be published; AND
> - Agreement to be accountable for all aspects of the work in ensuring that questions related to the accuracy or integrity of any part of the work are appropriately investigated and resolved.
>
> In addition to being accountable for the parts of the work he or she has done, an author should be able to identify which co-authors are responsible for specific other parts of the work. In addition, authors should have confidence in the integrity of the contributions of their co-authors.
>
> All those designated as authors should meet all four criteria for authorship, and all who meet the four criteria should be identified as authors. Those who do not meet all four criteria should be acknowledged...

Although you would clearly have made a substantial contribution to the paper, and your work so far would probably be sufficient qualify under point 2, the fact that you've left the company could be a serious obstacle to points 3 and 4.

Would you be happy with an acknowledgement rather than authorship? If not, you should be prepared to discuss with your manager how you might review the final text to approve it (point 3) and have access to data for any investigation necessary under point 4. It might be possible to arrange some kind of non-disclosure agreement which would reassure the company that you won't try to gain competitive advantage for your new company from any additional research which makes it into the paper, or to steal data.

Comment: Peter - thoroughly appreciate your input. These are good points that I had not considered. I will check with the relevant journals for similar clauses.

Comment: The journal I'm targeting conforms to the specific criteria you mention. Point 3 and 4 will be difficult to get around. Though the people I work with are decent, I doubt I could get access to make changes (especially if this requires using data) after leaving. This is certainly a good basis to proceed on though.

Answer (score 2):

I used to work in academia and I now work in the UK Civil Service.

---

> If my team go ahead and eventually publish a report on this project based on this work, do I have any claim to authorship?

Not really. Because there isn't a guarantee that a paper will be published, then it's hard to claim authorship. Moreover, most contracts I've seen say that what is produced in the workplace is solely owned by the business.

> Is there any enforceable basis to ensure that, if I leave, and it is published, my credit is kept?

I wouldn't be able to advise on this, seeing as I'm not a lawyer. I've never heard of a contract that would compel an employer to acknowledge authorship.

But there is good news! You don't have to seek a legal route through this. When you hand in your notice, I would discuss authorship with your manager. If you can dig through over publications and find a precedent of attributed authorship after someone leaves, then I think that strengthens your case.

Comment: `When you hand in your notice, I would discuss authorship with your manager.` Sounds pretty reasonable. I like the idea of establishing some historical norm from previous studies.